# iptables port forwarding: Unknown arg

Tags: linux, tcp, port, iptables, portforwarding

I am trying to do port forwarding with iptables

I am having the problem **'Unknown arg `--to-destination'** when trying to execute this command

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:80
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Which kernel version and which iptables version are you using? Try loading the `iptable_nat` module explicitly...

Comment: kernel 2.6.25 and iptables v1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the traffic?

If yes
on prerouting use `-j REDIRECT --to 192.168.1.2:80`
If no
Sorry.